# pljava installation 1.5.1-snapshot on postgresql 10beta2 - undefined symbol: DatumGetFloat8

Tags: postgresql, pljava

When installing pljava-1.5.1-snapshot on postgresql 10b2 I get 
`undefined symbol: DatumGetFloat8` when executing
`create extension pljava;`

Works for me on postgres96.

Is there an issue installing pljava on the upcomming postgresql version? Can somebody please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report. This was not a known issue against 10b1. I'll see if I can reproduce it with 10b2.

Edit: works fine for me with 10b2. Is there any chance that the PL/Java build you are trying to use with your PG 10b2 installation was actually built against a PG version < 10? If you did the build yourself and you had more than one PG version available, Maven will have built against the one whose `pg_config` executable was found first on the search path ... though you can also use `-Dpgsql.pgconfig=` on the `mvn` command line to force building against a specific version (by pointing to the `pg_config` executable in that version's `bin` directory).

PostgreSQL upstream changed `DatumGetFloat8` from an external function to an inlined one [for PG 10](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;f=src/include/postgres.h;h=14cca1bf8e31ed39dbc26dd6c610f1113e759972), so if you happened to build PL/Java against an older PG version, it would still be trying to link an external `DatumGetFloat8` that, in PG 10, isn't there any more.

Edit: by the way, I would recommend building and using `1.5.1-BETA1` instead of `1.5.1-SNAPSHOT` at this stage, so that once `1.5.1` is released, you will be able to move from `1.5.1-BETA1` to `1.5.1` with a simple `ALTER EXTENSION ... UPDATE`. From a snapshot version, `ALTER EXTENSION` will not know how to update.